# Toda-Yamamoto Mutually Causal Relationship between I(0) and I(1) Variables

Tags: chi-squared-test, p-value, vector-autoregression, f-test, granger-causality

I want to sanity check some results. I've run a TY causality test following the Toda-Yamamoto (TY) procedure as described by Dave Giles in his blog post ["Testing for Granger Causality"](http://davegiles.blogspot.be/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html). One variable is stationary at level (I(0)) and one is stationary at its first difference (I(1)). Following the TY procedure, I've constructed a VAR using $p+d$ lags, where $p$ is recommended by AIC and $d=1$ (the max order of integration, as one variable is I(1)). The inputs to the VAR were all variables *at level* (following Giles procedure, I did not difference the I(1) variable to do a causality test).

I ran a Wald test following the TY procedure for both. Specifically, I excluded the coefficients of the $p+d$th lag term (using only the initial $p$ lags, and not the additional lag added for the I(1) variable as per Giles/TY). The Chi-Square $p$-values are quite low for both directions - 0.005 and 0.0006. The $F$-test $p$-values are 0.097 and 0.063, respectively.

Am I allowed to look at the $F$-test $p$-values using the TY procedure? Does the fact that cointegrations *cannot* exist between an I(1) and I(0) variable mean I've done something wrong, as it appears mutual causality exists?